# Make the background color red for each row in the listview where the Quantity of each item has a 0 value?

Tags: c#, sql-server, listview

I have a listview that loads the data of the Menu table in the database (MsSql 2012). The table has four columns ID, Product, Price and Quantity. So I am trying to make the rows of each items in the listview that will go red if the quantity in the database is 0. I've set the quantities of each Products so that I can identify if it will work. Apparently this is my code right now, but nothing happens when I put the method redRowL in the Form1_Load.

Note: The listview only loads the ID, Product and Price.

```
public void redRowL()
{
    try
    {
        foreach(ListViewItem item in listView2.Items)
        {
            SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection();
            con.Open();
            string qwe = "Select " +  item.SubItems[0].Text  + " from Menu where Quantity = 0";

            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(qwe, con);
            dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            while (dr.Read())
            {
                item.BackColor = Color.Red; 
            }
        }
    }
    catch
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Rows are Red , Your eye is Blue, What will you do if I'm in love with you?", "PHugOts Error");
    }
    con.Close();
}
```

Comment: it seems the problem is with your sql query, why to select `item.SubItems[0].Text`?

Comment: Try use `string qwe = "Select Product from Menu where Quantity = 0";` instead of   `string qwe = "Select " +  item.SubItems[0].Text  + " from Menu where Quantity = 0";`

Comment: I am selecting the item.SubItems[0].Text that contains the MenuID for each product that has a 0 quantity , so that when the Form Loads the query will identify which products who  has a 0 quantity and it should make the back color of the each row to red